# What do the "ALL"s in the line " %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL " in Ubuntu's /etc/sudoers file stand for?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, sudo, sudoers

What does each ALL mean? I understand that the whole line indicates that the admin group members get admininstartive privileges, but would like to know more info about the position of the ALLS and if they each refer to a different set of permissions or something like that?

```
$sudo cat /etc/sudoers
...
# User privilege Information
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
#...
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

#Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
```

If it matters:
OS: Ubuntu : 10.4

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a manual page for **[sudoers(5)](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.8.2/sudoers.man.html)**.

Basically:

- **`%admin`** – the *group* named "`admin`" (`%` prefix)
- **`ALL=`** – on all hosts (if you distribute the same `sudoers` file to many computers)
- **`(ALL)`** – as any target user
- **`ALL`** – can run any command

A more restricted example would be:

```
%mailadmin   snow,rain=(root) /usr/sbin/postfix, /usr/sbin/postsuper, /usr/bin/doveadm
nobody       ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/rndc reload
```

In this case, the group `mailadmin` is allowed to run mail server control tools as user `root` on hosts named "`snow`" and "`rain`". The user `nobody` is allowed to run `rndc reload` as root, on all hosts, without being asked for any password. (Normally sudo asks for the invoker's own password.)

Comment: What about the extra "ALL" after the ":" in "ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL"?

Comment: @colan: List of allowed *groups* for switching with the `-g` option. It's under "User Specification" in the manpage.